ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _rust: The specified procedure could not be found
I have been trying to run a quick start flask app for the first time via PyCharm / VSCode. My pip is fully upgraded to the latest version, and I have installed requirements.txt in my venv, but when I try to run it, I see this error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abdul\Downloads\Quickstart App-1-python\Quickstart App-1-python\app\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, session, current_app
  File "C:\Users\abdul\Downloads\Quickstart App-1-python\Quickstart App-1-python\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .app import Flask as Flask
  File "C:\Users\abdul\Downloads\Quickstart App-1-python\Quickstart App-1-python\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 15, in <module>
    import click
  File "C:\Users\abdul\Downloads\Quickstart App-1-python\Quickstart App-1-python\app\click\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .utils import create_click_api_client
  File "C:\Users\abdul\Downloads\Quickstart App-1-python\Quickstart App-1-python\app\click\utils.py", line 1, in <module>
    from docusign_click import ApiClient
  File "C:\Users\abdul\Downloads\Quickstart App-1-python\Quickstart App-1-python\venv\lib\site-packages\docusign_click\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .apis.accounts_api import AccountsApi
  File "C:\Users\abdul\Downloads\Quickstart App-1-python\Quickstart App-1-python\venv\lib\site-packages\docusign_click\apis\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .accounts_api import AccountsApi
  File "C:\Users\abdul\Downloads\Quickstart App-1-python\Quickstart App-1-python\venv\lib\site-packages\docusign_click\apis\accounts_api.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ..client.api_client import ApiClient
  File "C:\Users\abdul\Downloads\Quickstart App-1-python\Quickstart App-1-python\venv\lib\site-packages\docusign_click\client\api_client.py", line 25, in <module>
    import jwt
  File "C:\Users\abdul\Downloads\Quickstart App-1-python\Quickstart App-1-python\venv\lib\site-packages\jwt\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .api_jwk import PyJWK, PyJWKSet
  File "C:\Users\abdul\Downloads\Quickstart App-1-python\Quickstart App-1-python\venv\lib\site-packages\jwt\api_jwk.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .algorithms import get_default_algorithms, has_crypto, requires_cryptography
  File "C:\Users\abdul\Downloads\Quickstart App-1-python\Quickstart App-1-python\venv\lib\site-packages\jwt\algorithms.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils import (
  File "C:\Users\abdul\Downloads\Quickstart App-1-python\Quickstart App-1-python\venv\lib\site-packages\jwt\utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ec import EllipticCurve
  File "C:\Users\abdul\Downloads\Quickstart App-1-python\Quickstart App-1-python\venv\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\ec.py", line 11, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat._oid import ObjectIdentifier
  File "C:\Users\abdul\Downloads\Quickstart App-1-python\Quickstart App-1-python\venv\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\_oid.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _rust: The specified procedure could not be found.

I have tried to following solutions:

Uninstall and install cryptography
Install rustc
Upgraded pip to the latest version

I'm having trouble finding the exact DLL that is causing this problem; these are my requirements.txt:
astroid==3.1.0
certifi==2024.2.2
cffi==1.16.0
chardet==5.2.0
Click
cryptography==42.0.5
docusign-esign==4.0.0rc1
docusign-rooms==1.3.0
docusign-monitor==1.2.0
docusign-click==1.4.0
docusign-admin==1.4.1
docusign-webforms==1.0.2rc12
docusign-maestro==2.0.0rc1
Flask==2.3.3
Flask-OAuthlib==0.9.6
Flask-Session==0.8.0
flask-wtf==1.2.1
flake8==7.0.0
idna==3.7
isort==5.13.2
itsdangerous==2.2.0
Jinja2>=3.1.3
lazy-object-proxy==1.10.0
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
mccabe==0.7.0
oauthlib==2.1.0
pipenv==2023.12.1
py-oauth2==0.0.10
pycparser==2.22
pylint==3.1.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==1.0.1
requests>=2.31.0
requests-oauthlib==1.1.0
six==1.16.0
urllib3>=2.2.1
virtualenv==20.25.3
virtualenv-clone==0.5.7
Werkzeug==2.3.8
wrapt==1.16.0

What are the possible ways I can look into this solution, or if anyone has faced a similar error, how can this be fixed?

As already mentioned here How to solve "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _rust ..." I also installed an earlier version of cryptography==40.0.2 and it worked.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
